Can we use 90 degrees elbow on horizontal drain pipe
My plumber added a 90 degree elbow on laundry drain horizontal pipe which is connected to building drain, is this by code or not?

Which code?  Which jurisdiction?  There isn't a planet Earth plumbing code!

Depends on the 90 degree elbow. Some are designed for drain use, some are not. Hopefully a plumber would know enough to choose the correct type for the use. Without a photo, no way to tell.
